# How to check, if the date older than 5 days return ture in groovy no the other date lib

Tags: date, groovy

I have a question, how to check in groovy, if the the date older than 5 days comparing with now.

```
def now = new Date() : Wed Feb 23 11:05:06 CET 2022
String testDate = "2002-2-10"

I have 2 input dates : Fri Feb 11 17:17:42 2022 +0100
and Wed Feb 23 11:05:06 CET 2022
```

How can I check, if testDate oder than 5 days?

any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can check for difference in days like so:

```
Date minus5 = new Date() - 5
```

Beware though, that in order to do this and other date-related ops like formatting or parsing, you have to add https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-dateutil to your dependencies.

If you cann't do that, you can use good-ol milliseconds based approach:

```
Date minus5 = new Date( System.currentTimeMillis() - 5l * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 )
```